# transferring files from the singularity container into the local directory

Tags: singularity-container

I have made `singulaty` image and run that. it works perfectly because when I look at the container using this command:

```
singularity shell image_name
```

I can see the output. so the question is that, how can I copy the files from the container into the local directory?

Answer (score 1):

This will get your image's file in the current working directory:

```
singularity  exec  <image path or url> cp <file in container> .
```

Answer (score 0):

By default your home and current working directory are mounted into the image, so you can copy the desired files directly to either of those directories.