# Change singularity home directory to a folder within the container

Tags: singularity-container

### Background

I have a singularity container that was created from a docker image. The docker image has files that are meant to be in the user's home directory (e.g. in `$HOME/.files`).  Because I don't know what the username will be, I put the files in `/opt` in the container and want to set the user's home to `/opt`.

I would like to be able to run the container with `/opt` as the home directory, OR somehow be able to run the container so that the home directory contains the files *that already exist within the container*

### What I have tried:

- use the `--home` flag : This maps a folder on the host as the home directory, rather than a folder in the container.
- try overriding the `$HOME` environment variable with `--env HOME=/opt` : I get the error `Overriding HOME environment variable with SINGULARITYENV_HOME is not permitted`

### Other questions

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893569/changing-the-home-folder-in-a-singularity-container) is related, but interested in mapping the container's home folder to a folder on the host machine

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $HOME shell environment variable when you bind the two directories.

singularity exec -B $HOME:/opt example_container.sif touch /opt/file

Here is the documentation on [singularity's bind](https://singularity-userdoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bind_paths_and_mounts.html) feature